# Counterexample: linearly ordered sets for which there exists more than one isomorphism

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples, order-theory

In my axiomatic set theory notes, there appears that, if $A$ and $B$ are well-ordered isomorphic sets, then there exists one isomorphism between them. However, as a side note, it is stated that this fact apparently distinguishes only-linearly orderded sets from well-ordered ones.

In the case where $A=B$, that is, considering the special case where we are studying the existence of automorphisms on $A$ that are different from the identity, $\text{id}_{A}$, one can easily find that, in $\mathbb{R}$ with its usual order there are plenty of counterexamples that prove this claim; for instance, considering different translations of the points of $\mathbb{R}$

However, I have not yet encountered a single counterexample that proves this in the case where $A\not=B$, that is, a couple of distinct linearly ordered sets that are isomorphic via several dstinct automorphisms.

I would guess that this counterexample should involve some subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, because the majority of sets we have encountered in this course, like the ordinal numbers, are all well ordered sets with their natural order relation.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: That "distinguishes" assertion is interesting.  Can we prove that *any* linearly ordered, but not well ordered, set admits an automorphism other than the identity?

Comment: Actually, that is an interesting question, but I don't necessarily need to know whether it's true or not, or how to prove/disprove such a claim.

Comment: I think that the "distinguishes" that appears in my notes is not intended to mean "characterizes", though.

Comment: @GEdgar No, we can't. Any reverse well-ordering is rigid as well. And there are further examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix an order-isomorphism $(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ and compose it with any order-isomorphism $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Each order-isomorphism $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ then gives rise to a distinct order-isomorphism $(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: More generally this shows that the 2 questions "are there many isomorphisms between these two things ?" and "does any of them have many automorphisms ?" are the same

Comment: @Max Or, using fancier words, in a connected component of a groupoid, the automorphism group of any object is the same.

Comment: @lisyarus well actually it's more relating the automorphism group to the $\hom$-set in a groupoid, but anyway it's mostly the same thing

Comment: Pff, totally missed the obvious tangent function. I am still going to keep this answer, though.